# Не выбирается строка из query, остается пустым TextView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Предыдущая Activity без проблем добавляет и считывает данные из БД

*Функция выбора:*

```java
    public Cursor getc(String name){
        Cursor c=db.query("car",null,"name = ?",new String[] {name},null,null,null);
        return c;
    }
```

*Главная Activity:*

```java
    Cursor c= DBManager.getc(name);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do{
            String sr = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyConstants.KEY_SR));
            srv.setText(sr);
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }
```

Comment: Маловато контекста для ответа на не очень чётко сформулированный вопрос. Остаётся лишь гадать. Моё предположение - вы из одной активити пытаетесь вызвать метод другой активити. Коли так - то такое делать и нельзя и не нужно. Также вам стоит обратить внимание на библиотеку room для БД. Курсорами в реальной жизни почти никто не пользуется, т.к. это дико неудобно и нет защиты от опечаток.

Comment: У меня создан класс DBManager для работы с БД, в котором хранятся методы, разве такой вариант нельзя использовать?

Comment: Можно, но и это можно делать неправильно. В кусках кода, которые вы показали, ничего подозрительного нет. Проверьте под отладчиком что там происходит.